# How to zoom to a GeoJSON feature on map using OpenLayers 3 following a WFS request

Tags: javascript, openlayers

After doing a WFS request, I have fetched all GeoJSON objects and fill in a list. My goal is to zoom specified GeoJSON in fetched all GeoJSON using OpenLayers 3.

In the below code inside the `showFeatureByID` function, I have reached specified GeoJSON by clicking, after this, I would like to zoom in on map using OpenLayers.

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {

    var view = map.getView();
    var viewResolution = view.getResolution();
    var source = untiled.get('visible') ? untiled.getSource() : tiled.getSource();
    var url = source.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
        evt.coordinate, viewResolution, view.getProjection(),
        {'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json', 'FEATURE_COUNT': 50});

    if (url) {
        //url includes getFeatureInfo request string and use x,y values on map to find clicked object.
        // do wms getFeatureInfo request.
        loadDoc(url);
        interval1 = setInterval(function () {
            if (featureData.status == true) {
                fillDataView(featureData.data[0]);
                showFeatureByID(featureData.data[0]["ID"]);
                clearInterval(interval1);
            }
        }, 100);
    }
});


var featureData;
var allGeoJSONFeatures={};

function loadDoc(url) {
    featureData={status:false,data:[]};
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

             var jsonObject=JSON.parse(this.response);

             for(i in jsonObject){
                 var val = jsonObject[i];
                 if(i == "features"){
                     for(j in val){
                         var geojsonx = val[j];
                         var properties = geojsonx.properties;
                         featureData.data.push(properties);
                     }
                 }
             }
            if(featureData.data.length>0){
                featureData.status=true;
            }
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xhttp.send();
}


function getAllGeoJSON() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var jsonObject=JSON.parse(this.response);
            var json = jsonObject.features;
            for(i in json){
                var id = json[i].properties.ID;
                allGeoJSONFeatures["p"+id] = json[i];
            }

        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://ip:host/geoserver/xxx/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=BaskentGaz:M_DIZAYN_VANA&outputFormat=application%2Fjson", true);
    xhttp.send();
}


function showFeatureByID(id) {

    var geojson = allGeoJSONFeatures["p"+id];
    alert(geojson.toString());

}
```

Comment: As this is a question about WFS, you should remove the WMS GetFeatureInfo code as it does not appear to be relevant.  You need to add what you have tried relevant to the question of zooming.